# Check box attribute disabled not working in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem is that I am unable to set `disabled` attribute to disabled using jQuery. I am able to set `checked` property but not `disabled` property. Any help will be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="special-review">
<label></label>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkspecialreview" TabIndex="26" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="chkspecialreview" Text="Exam requires special review" />
 </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#chkspecialreview").attr('checked', 'checked'); // This is working

$("#chkspecialreview").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // This is not working
$("#chkspecialreview").attr('disabled', true); // This is not working
$("#chkspecialreview").prop('disabled', true); // This is not working
```

Comment: Do you get any error in your console?

Comment: No. Just disabled property is not working in my code .. i can set $("#chkspecialreview").prop('enabled', 'false');

Comment: What jQuery are you using? It should work...

Comment: jquery 1.11.0 with jquery-migrate 1.2.1

Comment: just disabled attr is not working but enabled is working. this is asp control.

Answer (score 0):

Using *jQuery* v2.1.1 seems to be working. You should check if the content is in `DOM` before applying the change.
Using `.attr("disabled", true);` works as expected (as seen in the snippet below).

```js
$("#check").attr("checked", true);
$("#check").attr("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
```